# ie 11 wierd shaking on scrolling

Tags: html, css, fixed, internet-explorer-11, background-attachment

I have a Issue. I'm currently working on a site but decided to not really pay attetion to IE since its an one page site and we have a selected audiance so we decided IE isnt a main priority.

Now I was doing some testing in ie 11 just for fun and everything seems to work pretty well. I only have 1 problem with the fixed background.

Whenever I try to scroll it shakes instead of just staying on its place. (so it is fixed but it still shakes up and down a few pixels when scrolling)

I also have a menu at the top which use scrolltop to scroll to the right div when clicking a menu item and when you use this the background image dont shake and behaves like it should be.

For anyone having windows 8 and ie 11 this is the link: http://www.randomshirts.nl/letterfabriek9/

UPDATE: when I test it on my normal computer ie11 its working fine. it seems to be a problem with the touchscreen laptop

Comment: Cannot reproduce the advised problem in W7 / IE11

Comment: works perfect... ie 11 / Win 8

Comment: no wierd shoking of the first bg image when scrolling manually?

Comment: @epynic and @Paulie_D try it on an element other than `body`.

Answer (score -3):

Try saving the background image in .jpg and try lowering the pixels and also make it sure that your IE is fully updated.

Comment: they are jpg and I've runned them trough multiple image optimizers. and still it would be wierd that it is working when using scrolltop to navigate and not when scrolling manually